# PowerMockito Error

Tags: mockito, apache-kafka, junit4, powermockito

Need a quick help. I am trying to write a test class and getting below error
"can not resolve the method .thenreturn(org.apache.kafka.clients.producer)

```
@Test
public void testPublishData_Success() throws java.lang.Exception {
    when(GetPropValues.getPropValue(PublisherConstants.ATMID)).thenReturn("ATM");
    when(GetPropValues.getPropValue(PublisherConstants.DATA_SOURCE)).thenReturn("PCE");

    ReadAndWriteFiles mockFiles = Mockito.mock(ReadAndWriteFiles.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(ReadAndWriteFiles.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(mockFiles);
    Mockito.when(mockFiles.getAllFiles()).thenReturn("someValue");

    KafkaProducer mockProducer = Mockito.mock(KafkaProducer.class);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(KafkaProducer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockProducer);

    producer.publishData(null, "Test", "Data1");
}
```

Powermockito is fine in returning ReadAndWriteFiles.class object but it is throwing an error for KafkaProducer.class. on line

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(KafkaProducer.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockProducer);
```

Is there any other way to for this work around? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Note: KafkaProducer.class is in not a custom class but its inside from apache spark kafka libraries

Main code is as per below

```
KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);
            InputData inputMessage;
            try {
                inputMessage = populateData(timeStamp, dataCategory, data, atmId, topic);
                ReadAndWriteFiles readerWriter = new ReadAndWriteFiles();
                File[] directory = readerWriter.getAllFiles();
                if (directory != null && directory.length > 0) {
                    if (connectionSet && !publishingData) {
                        sendDataFromFiles(producer, directory);
                        publishingData = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    producer.send(keyedMsg, new KafkaResponseHandler(inputMessage));
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is

```
KafkaProducer mockProducer = Mockito.mock(KafkaProducer.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(ReadAndWriteFiles.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mockProducer)
```

I think the returned value should be a mock for `ReadAndWriteFiles` class not a `KafkaProducer`

```
ReadAndWriteFiles readMock = Mockito.mock(ReadAndWriteFiles.class)
PowerMockito.whenNew(ReadAndWriteFiles.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(readMock)

Mockito.when(readMock.getAllFiles()).thenReturn(anArrayOfFiles);
```

The signature of the `thenReturn` method is as follow

```
OngoingStubbing<T>  [More ...] thenReturn(T value);
```

So you are using to return a `ReadAndWriteFiles` you shouls return an object of the same class

Comment: I need to check if I am doing something stupid or not, Let me check and get back to you tomorrow morning. And Thanks much for your help Koitoer.

Comment: You are right Koitoer, It was a silly mistake, I should have caught that my self. Sorry for wasting your time and Thanks again for your help.